# how to delete item in dropdown list wffm

Tags: wffm, sitecore-query

can we delete list item in WFFM?
[image]

I want to delete "3HUTCHISON" from dropdown field, but when i clicked (x)(delete) nothing happened.

i am new to sitecore, i need to make 48 items for dropdown list and i need to cut into 32 items :/

Comment: Do you have any errors in the log files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understood what is happening. Your value was locked out after saving the list. You need to click on the "Value" label and confirm that you want to change the value. After that you will be able to remove the row.

[image: unlock editing]

and confirm:

[image]

Comment: OH Thanks! i dunno that we can click value.is it effected to the old report? i mean if i delete one item like "3HUTCHISON", The old report still has this value right?

Comment: I am not sure, but I guess yes, report will has the submitted value even if it is already deleted.